# DDD: In which layer should i place webservices (both to serve requests and webreferences to external ones)?

Tags: web-services, domain-driven-design

I'm studying the layers at this momment and i'm wondering where each one should be placed. The webservices i am going to write, in my understanding, should be placed as new projects in the application services layer, acessing domain services in order to feed repositories once some new registry is pushed through it (the webservice will both serve searching and insertions to the database).

The second possibility i thought of would be the webservice to be placed into the presentation layer, having it's own project in the application services layer to process it's requests and access the domain services.

About the external webservices, the webreferences, once again, according to what i understand of DDD, should be placed in the infrastructure layer and the domain services, trough a repository that has it's interface in the domain layer but is placed in the infrastructure layer, would connect to the external webservice and fire the requests.

Any thoughts? I don't think it's based purely on opinion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two scenarios.

**1. You have a web service that someone can call to interact with your application**

This web service "*uses*" your application, thus it should sit outside of your application. It will **only know about your application layer** and to interact with the domain it will call methods on the application layer.

**2. You are calling a web service from your application**

In this case that call will live in the integration layer. It can either be accessed via the application layer directly, or you can have an interface in the domain layer, that you implement in the integration layer. This depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, those are the exact scenarios i will be working on. I was not sure wether the 1st scenario's webservice would be placed in the presentation layer, in a new 'services' layer, or directly as a new application in the application layer. I guess that the best solution is placing it in a services layer calling methods from the application layer, so i can change the behavior of the application itself without harming the interface provided by the webservice using dependecy injection as it's widely encourage by DDD.

Comment: As for the 2nd scenario i think you've confirmed my approach. I'll create an interface in the domain layer for a repository in the infrastructure layer that consumes the webservice, being this repository only used in the applications in the app layer.